# In how many ways can 40 identical carrots be distributed among 8 different rabbits?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can 40 identical carrots be distributed among 8 different rabbits, while every rabbit needs to get a carrot, and no rabbit get more then 16 carrots.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are asking for the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $40$ where every term in the partition is less than or equal to $16$. I think there's no known closed-form formula for the number of partitions, so you'll have to simply compute this by systematically trying all possibilities

Comment: @vrugtehagel  This is a [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) rather than a partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose rabbit $j$ get $x_j$ carrots. 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^8 x_j=40
$$
Number of positive solutions less than $17$ of the last equation is coefficient of $z^{40}$ in
$$
(z^1+z^2+\cdots+z^{16})^8={z^8(1-z^{16})^8\over(1-z)^8}
$$
Or equivalently coefficient of $z^{40}$ in
$$
z^8(1-8z^{16}+28z^{32})\sum_{k=0}^{32}\binom{8+k-1}{k}z^{k}\\
=\binom{8+32-1}{32}-8\binom{8+16-1}{16}+28\\
=13419709$$

Answer (score 0):

This is only a part of a solution.

Give 1 carrot to each rabbit. You have 24 remaining, since the first condition forces you give each rabbit at least one. 
Next, the problem is: In how many ways can 24 be partitioned 24 so none of the parts is greater then 16.

I have no clue what the answer above is calculating. I only understood that $x_i$ are carrots.

I have opened this Problem here:
[In how many ways to partition(ordered partition) an natural number n so none of the parts is greater then k?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370398/in-how-many-ways-to-partitionordered-partition-an-natural-number-n-so-none-of)